# Why is there a difference in coordinate system Cycles obj normals vs. Blender Render obj normals?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, texture-baking

Baking normals of a geometry in Cycles and in Blender Render results in two different colours (coordinate systems), although both are set to "object space".
When I calculate normals with C++ code, I get same result image as in Cycles.

Blender Render baking.
[image: Blender normals in obj space.][image: Blender bake settings]

Cycles baking.
[image: Cycles normals in obj space (+x+y+z)][image: Cycles bae settings]

C++ VTK class vtkPolyDataNormals.
[image: C++ VTK generated normals.]

Why is that? What does Blender Render do differently?

Comment: In Cycles set bake space to "object" and Swizzle to +X -Y -Z to get same colors as in Blender Render.

Comment: On developer.blender.org I was told that: "_This is by design, for Cycles we chose to follow the more common standard, but didn't change Blender Internal to keep it backwards compatible. Blender Internal will be removed in 2.80 so once that's done it will all be consistent._"

Comment: Mapping of coordinates to color values in Blender Render are mentioned in the [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/bump_normal.html).